# Error ORA-12899 when executing a query

Tags: java, oracle

I'm trying to set a string with one character in it in my prepared statement like this:

```
ps.setString(7, String.valueOf(concretizada));
```

But here's the thing: my db column has size of one. And even if it's just one character, an exception is being thrown:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12899: valor muito grande para a coluna "QPL"."TAB_NEGC"."FL_CONCR" (real: 8, máximo: 1)

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:447)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:951)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:513)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:227)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:208)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForRows(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1046)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1336)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3694)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1354)
    at br.com.reajuste.repositorio.RepositorioTabelaNegociacao.inserirTabela(RepositorioTabelaNegociacao.java:1451)
    at br.com.reajuste.repositorio.RepositorioTabelaNegociacao.inserirTabelaNegociacao(RepositorioTabelaNegociacao.java:855)
    at br.com.reajuste.repositorio.RepositorioTabelaNegociacao.copiarTabelas(RepositorioTabelaNegociacao.java:837)
    at br.com.reajuste.controlador.ControladorReajuste.executarReajuste(ControladorReajuste.java:33)
    at br.com.reajuste.gui.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

(Value too large for column)

How can i set a char as a parameter in a prepared statement?

EDIT: my 'concretizada' variable:

```
String concretizada = "N";
        if (tabelaNegociacao.getConcretizada()) {
            concretizada = "S";
        }
```

Comment: What is the value of `concretizada`?

Comment: trim() the String and see. May be spaces in String causing the problem.

Comment: Maximum allowed is 1 character for "FL_CONCR" column, you are passing 8 characters

Comment: The error you posted says you have a String of length `8` that you're trying to fit in a column of length `1`.

Comment: Edited with the definition of 'concretizada'.

Comment: Can you please post the DDL for `"QPL"."TAB_NEGC"`?

Comment: There's some other `setString(7,....)` which is overwriting your expected one? ?

Comment: No. There's only one setString(7,....)

Comment: @JoaoVictor Can you please post how you create the table? (I mean the SQL)

Comment: The column is defined like this: CHAR(1 BYTE)

Comment: @JoaoVictor That was my suspect. See my answer

Answer (score 1):

The DDL doesn't say that `FL_CONCR` is 1 char long. It says that `FL_CONCR` is 1 **byte** long.

A character can take multiple bytes, based on how it is encoded.

Change it to this:

```
FL_CONCR VARCHAR2(1 CHAR)
```

And it should work.

If you don't want to re-create the table:

```
ALTER TABLE TAB_NEGC MODIFY(FL_CONCR VARCHAR2(1 CHAR));
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to solve this without changing the definition of the column?

Comment: @JoaoVictor Unfortunately, no. As I wrote, a character can have variable size in bytes, based on how it is encoded. i.e. UTF-8 can take from 1 to 4 bytes to store the character.